# Regular expression to determine website root

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following url's and all these url are considered root of the website, how can I use javascript location.pathname using regex to determine pattern below, as you'll notice the word "site" is repeating in this pattern..

```
 http://www.somehost.tv/sitedev/
 http://www.somehost.tv/sitetest/
 http://www.somehost.tv/site/

 http://www.somehost.tv/sitedev/index.html
 http://www.somehost.tv/sitetest/index.html
 http://www.somehost.tv/site/index.html
```

I am attempting to display jQuery dialog only and only if the user is at the root of the website.

Comment: I tried following regex /^\/|index\.html|$/i.test(location.pathname);

Comment: Hoping to find what? come on... edit your question, add the code with which you've tried this. Add its output/results and tell us what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete pattern, including protocol and domain, could be like this:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.somehost\.tv\/site(test|dev)?\/(index\.html)?$/
```

but, if you're matching against `location.pathname` just try

```
/^\/site(test|dev)?\/(index\.html)?$/.test(location.pathname)
```

Comment: I tested using this, but it 
var site = 'http://www.somehost.tv/sitetest/'
var isRoot = /^\/site(test|dev)?\/(index\.html)?$/.test(site);

alert(isRoot);

Comment: this cannot work. Your `site` string is starting with `somehost.tv` while my last regular expression checks the pathname. Use the first pattern instead

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the DOM to parse this. No need to invoke a regex parser.

```
var url = 'http://www.somesite.tv/foobar/host/site';
    urlLocation = document.createElement('a');

urlLocation.href = url;
alert(urlLocation.hostname);    // alerts 'www.somesite.tv'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitly need a Regular Expression for this

You also could do for example

- Fill an array with your urls
- Loop over a decreasing substring of

  - the shortest element.
- Comparing it against

  - the longest element.
- Until they match.

---

```
 var urls = ["http://www.somehost.tv/sitedev/",
 "http://www.somehost.tv/sitetest/",
 "http://www.somehost.tv/site/",
 "http://www.somehost.tv/sitedev/index.html",
 "http://www.somehost.tv/sitetest/index.html",
 "http://www.somehost.tv/site/index.html"]

     function getRepeatedSub(arr) {
         var srt = arr.concat().sort();
         var a = srt[0];
         var b = srt.pop();
         var s = a.length;
         while (!~b.indexOf(a.substr(0, s))) {
             s--
         };
         return a.substr(0, s);
     }
 console.log(getRepeatedSub(urls)); //http://www.somehost.tv/site
```

Heres an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/emuxeq/1/edit)